# Creating waterfall/stacked line plot in Matpotlib using transforms

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a series of waveforms such that they are distributed equally along the y-axis. I believe that `matplotlib.transforms` is the way to go. I have something rudimentary working using this code:

```
import matplotlib.transforms
import matplotlib as mp
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
%matplotlib inline

ax = pl.gca()
n_levels = 10
t = np.arange(1000)/1000

offset_step = 1/(n_levels + 1)
for i in range(n_levels):
    offset = offset_step * (i + 1)
    o = mp.transforms.ScaledTranslation(0, offset, ax.transAxes)
    trans = mp.transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transData + o)
    y = np.sin(t*2*np.pi*10*i)
    p, = ax.plot(t, y, 'k-', transform=trans)

ax.axis(ymin=0, ymax=25)
```

This creates the following plot.

[image: actual]

Even thought the actual offsets, in axes coordinates, are 0.09 0.18 ... 0.82 0.91, the lines clearly are not appearing at those exact offsets! What am I doing wrong?

Edit: To answer some of the questions regarding why I can't just apply the offset in data-space rather than using an transform. This is a simpler form of a more complex transform I need to do where I want to be able to scale the amplitude of individual lines without having to adjust the y-axes limits. To do this, the actual y-transform is:

```
boxin = mp.transforms.Bbox([[0, 0], [1, 1]])
boxout = mp.transforms.Bbox([[0, 0], [1, 1]])
y_trans = mp.transforms.BboxTransform(boxin, boxout) + \
    axes.transData + \
    mp.transforms.ScaledTranslation(0, offset_step * (i + 1), axes.transAxes)
```

Then, in my interactive application, I can modify the scaling of each individual waveform using:

```
scale = 2
box = np.array([[0, 0], [scale, scale]])
boxout.set_points(box)
figure.canvas.redraw()
```

It works really well. However, for varying choices of `n_levels`, I need to initially adjust ymin and ymax when generating the plot to ensure the lines are spaced *equally* along the y-axis. The desired result is:

[image: desired]

Comment: What do you mean by distributed equally along the y-axis? In your plot, the height of your waveform (2 * amplitude) looks equal. Please include the desired output if possible

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this, why do you want to use the transform to offset some data in axes coordinates, why not use `y = np.sin(t*2*np.pi*10*i)+i*1.01` or similar?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I've updated my comment to answer your question.

Comment: @Bazingaa: I added a plot of my desired output. I generated the desired output by hand-editing some parameters, but I would want a more automatic approach if possible.

Comment: I have the impression that what you're doing only works by coincidence. Does the amplitude have any singnificance in data space?

Comment: I would just use an offset as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggested above.

Comment: So you want to adjust the Y axis or not?

Comment: @Brad The Y axis span will depend on the number of waveforms and their amplitude, you can't avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the y axis scale is apparently of no concern here, you may just follow the transform chain step by step

1. Start with a virtual box around the data, in this case from [-1,1].
2. Transform to the unit square
3. Transform to a virtual box that is `offset_step` in height.
4. Translate this box by `i*offset_step` (possibly add some space at the bottom)
5. Add the axes transform (because all of this happens in axes coordinates)

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()
n_levels = 10
t = np.arange(1000)/1000
T = t*2*np.pi*10

offset_step = 1/(n_levels+1)
space = 1.25 # set to 1 to have no space between lines

# Transform from a virtual box around the sine (-1 .. 1 in y direction)
tfrom = mtrans.BboxTransformFrom(mtrans.Bbox([[0, -1*space],[1, 1*space]]))
# Transform to a box (0 .. offset_step)
tto = mtrans.BboxTransformTo(mtrans.Bbox([[0, 0],[1,offset_step]]))


for i in range(n_levels):
    # offset = steps + half the remainder to full axes
    offset = offset_step * i + (1-n_levels*offset_step)/2.
    # Translate by offset
    translate = mtrans.Affine2D().translate(0,offset)
    # chain all transforms
    y_trans = tfrom + tto + translate + ax.transAxes
    trans = mpl.transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, y_trans)
    # plot
    p, = ax.plot(t, np.sin(T*i), transform=trans)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay accepting your answer. This is great. I didn't understand your original question. Yes, the y-axis scale isn't relevant here, so what you've done works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `transData` already incorporates `transAxes`, so when I was creating the scaled translation, I was transforming by `transAxes` twice. The trick is to set the y transform to `transLimits` + `transScale` + scaled translation:

```
import matplotlib.transforms
import matplotlib as mp
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
%matplotlib inline

ax = pl.gca()
n_levels = 10
t = np.arange(1000)/1000

offset_step = 1/(n_levels + 1)
for i in range(n_levels):
    offset = offset_step * (i + 1)
    o = mp.transforms.ScaledTranslation(0, offset, ax.transAxes)
    y_trans = ax.transLimits + ax.transScale + o
    trans = mp.transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, y_trans)
    y = np.sin(t*2*np.pi*10*i)
    p, = ax.plot(t, y, 'k-', transform=trans)
```

This generates:

[image: plot]

Which is exactly what I want.

Comment: At least this answers my question "Does the amplitude have any singnificance in data space?" with "no".

Comment: Having spend some more thought on this, I again think that this only works by cooincidence. A good test is if you can set arbitrary `ylim`s and still get the same plot; this does not seem to be the case in this code. E.g. if you add `plt.ylim(0,1)` here, the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58xEa.png).